# HOW do i save changes done in the highlighted cell in the show table into the Database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, onclick

I want to edit a cell in a database table using the given textbox show below.
at the end i am hoping to be able to edit that particular cell for any row in that give table

[image]

------------POST  Query

The below is the Post query for the update after the update button clicked

[image]

```
if(isset($_POST['del']))
{
$id=$_GET['del'];
$sql = "DELETE from users WHERE issuingitem_id=:id";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query -> bindParam(':id',$id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query -> execute();
$msg="Data Deleted successfully";

}


if (isset($_POST['NewQuanty'])){


    $acti=$_POST["rqustID"];
    $actid=$acti[0];
                                    $query1= $dbh -> prepare("SELECT distinct * FROM requestitem WHERE requestitem_id='$actid' ");
                  $query1->execute();
                    while ($row = $query1->fetch()){ 
                      $requstITM = $row['requestitem_item']?? '';  
                      $requstCLST = $row['requestitem_cluster']?? ''; 
                      $requstNUMB = $row['request_deptcartitm_NUMBER']?? '';                                  
                  }


    $actitmn=$requstITM; 
    $actclust=$requstCLST; 
    $actitnmb=$requstNUMB; 
    $actiapprvn=$_POST["NewQunty"];
    $actiapprvno=$actiapprvn[0];
    $activate = 1;

//------------EMAIL TRIGGER------------

 // include ('../script/emailTRIGGER-script.php');

//------------EMAIL TRIGGER------------

if ($actiapprvno == 0) {

$query1= $dbh -> prepare("UPDATE requestitem set requestitem_approvedNo = (requestitem_no) WHERE requestitem_id=:stffid LIMIT 1");
$query1-> bindParam(':stffid', $actid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
//$query1-> bindParam(':stffactve', $activate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query1->execute();
    header("location: cluster-request-made.php?deptcluster=$actclust");

}else {

            $query1 = $dbh -> prepare("UPDATE itemTABLE SET itemTABLE_acceptance ='$activate' WHERE itemTABLE_deptcartitm_NUMBER='$actitnmb' and itemTABLE_item= '$actitmn' ");
            $query1->execute();


$query1= $dbh -> prepare("UPDATE requestitem set requestitem_approvedNo = '$actiapprvno' WHERE requestitem_id=:stffid LIMIT 1");
$query1-> bindParam(':stffid', $actid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query1->execute();
    header("location: cluster-request-made.php?deptcluster=$actclust");
            }
}
```

------------Table Query

```
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">Listed  Items</div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
          <form method="post" class="form-horizontal"  enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" method="post" action="">
                            <?php if($error??''){?>'
                            <div class="errorWrap"><strong>ERROR</strong>:<?php echo htmlentities($error); ?> 
                            </div>
                        <?php } 
                else if($msg??''){?>
                    <div class="succWrap"><strong>SUCCESS</strong>:<?php echo htmlentities($msg); ?> 
                    </div>
                <?php }?>
                <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
                                <table id="zctb" class="display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                             <th>SERIAL #</th>
                             <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
                             <th>NAME</th>
                             <th>TOTAL</th>
                             <th style="width:150px">Change Quantity: </th>
                             <th>REQUESTOR</th>
                             <th>DATE REQUESTED</th>
                             <th>ACTION</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

<?php $sql = "SELECT * from requestitem WHERE requestitem_cluster = '$deptclstr' AND requestitem_collectdate = 'Not Yet' AND requestitem_Hclusterapprv = 2 and ( (requestitem_Haccountapprv = '0' and requestitem_FAapprv = '0') or (requestitem_Haccountapprv = '1' and  requestitem_FAapprv = '0') or (requestitem_Haccountapprv = '2' and  requestitem_FAapprv = '1') or (requestitem_Haccountapprv = '3')) ORDER BY requestitem_Haccountapprv, (requestitem_FAapprv) ASC" ;
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{

              $rqusthCLHDAPPRV = ($result->requestitem_Hclusterapprv);
            $rqustID = ($result->requestitem_id);
            $rqustNo = ($result->requestitem_approvedNo);
            $rqustITM = ($result->requestitem_item);
            $rqustCLST = ($result->requestitem_cluster);
            $rqustNUMB = ($result->request_deptcartitm_NUMBER);
            //$rqustQUNTY = array($_POST['NewQunty']);

        ?>  
                        <tr>

         <td style="font-size:15px"><?php echo htmlentities($result->request_NUMBER);?></td>
         <td style="font-size:15px"><?php echo htmlentities($result->requestitem_department);?></td>
         <td style="font-size:15px"><?php echo htmlentities($result->requestitem_item);?></td>
         <?php if  ($rqustNo ==0 || (empty($rqustNo))) { ?>
         <td style="width:15px"><?php echo htmlentities($result->requestitem_no);?>  </td>
         <?php } else { ?>
         <td style="width:15px"><?php echo htmlentities($result->requestitem_approvedNo);?>  </td>
         <?php } ?>
         <td style="font-size:15px">
                <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" name="NewQuanty" /> Yes / No            
                <div class="row" id="area" style="display: none;" >           
            <div style = "position:relative; left:15px; top:2px;">
            <input style="display:none;" style="font-size:15px" type="text" name="rqustID[]"  value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->requestitem_id);?>" readonly >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="NewQunty[]" data-toggle="dropdown" id="reply" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" placeholder="New Quantity"> | 
            <button style="font-size:15px" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>&nbsp; Update</button>
           </div></div>
         </td>
         <td style="font-size:15px"><?php echo htmlentities($result->requestitem_requestor);?></td>
         <td style="font-size:15px"><?php echo htmlentities($result->date_created);?></td>
                  <?php 
                        $dates = (date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
                        $requestitemN0 = $result->request_NUMBER;
                  $query1= $dbh -> prepare("SELECT distinct * FROM requestitem WHERE request_NUMBER='$requestitemN0' ORDER BY request_NUMBER");
                  $query1->execute(); 
                    while ($row = $query1->fetch()){ 
                      $requestNUMB = $row['request_NUMBER']?? '';                                    
                  }?>  
         <td style="font-size:15px"> 
                  <?PHP       if(($result->requestitem_Haccountapprv)==0)  {
                            echo '<a style="font-size:20px" href="script/update_status_clustarequest.php?id='.$result->requestitem_id.'&itemnam='.$result->requestitem_item.'&requstitemapprvdNo='.$result->requestitem_approvedNo.'&requstitemcluster='.$result->requestitem_cluster.'&itemnumb='.$result->request_deptcartitm_NUMBER.'&activation=1" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Confirm</a>'; 

                       //   echo '   <a style="font-size:20px" href="script/update_status_clustarequest.php?id='.$result->requestitem_id.'&itemnam='.$result->requestitem_item.'&requstitemapprvdNo='.$result->requestitem_approvedNo.'&itemnumb='.$result->request_deptcartitm_NUMBER.'&activation=2" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Forward to F & A</a>'; ?> 
                                                
                                                |  <input type="hidden" id="rjctrsn-data" href="" name="rejection_reason">  <a type="submit" name="rejectreason" onclick="showRejectionReasonAlert()" class="btn btn-xs delete-record" data-id="0"><span style="font-size:25px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger" style="color:red"></span></a> <?php
                       }else if ($rqusthCLHDAPPRV == 1) {
                         echo '<p><a style="font-size:20px" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Confirmed</a></p>';
```

Comment: If you want to edit something and submit it to the server, first you need a form and a submit button. In your HTML I can see the textbox, the checkbox and the button, but there is no `<form` tag as far as I can see. Or alternatively you need some JS code which can get the data from the right fields, and then submit it all in an AJAX request. Does that help? It's unclear where you are, in fact, stuck with this - "I want" is not a question or a problem statement (please take the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked materials, in order to get the best out of stackoverflow).